# Running Hortonworks Sandbox on Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, hortonworks-sandbox

I have imported Hortonworks Sandbox(HDP 2.6.1) on my Oracle Virtual Box(Version 5.0.24 r108355).When I click on this Sandbox and press start I'm facing the below error:

```
The configured driver wasn't found. Either the necessary driver modules wasn't loaded, the name was misspelled, or it was a misconfiguration. (VERR_PDM_DRIVER_NOT_FOUND).
```

I've tried with changing audio settings also.But unable to change them.

Any solution would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Sergey Kovalev for your comments.
Instead of import appliance option, tried with :

```
1.Create new virtual machine 
2.Select - Use an existing virtual hard disk file
3.Follow the steps for storage
4.Disable audio settings
```

After doing these steps able to start and work with Hortonworks Sandbox on Oracle Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be to ditch VirtualBox and use VMware or Docker instead:
https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/section/3/